# Standard #ifdef for Cygwin

Tags: c, macros, cygwin, c-preprocessor

If I want to know if I'm compiling on Cygwin, what is the standard macro to check for?

I've seen `#ifdef _WIN32`, but this doesn't seem future-proof or Cygwin specific.

Answer (score 25):

Seems like `#ifdef __CYGWIN__` works.

Found it on [this list](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/)